# Apache poi set page layout for XSSFSheet

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I am trying to set page layout in excel file using apache poi. I am using the following code:

```
  FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("Test.xlsx");
  xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
  XSSFSheet sheet = xssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
  CTSheetView view = sheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetViews().getSheetViewArray(0);
  view.setView(STSheetViewType.PAGE_LAYOUT);
```

It works fine if I create a new sheet and call the function on that. However, if I open an existing excel file and try to set all the sheet in page layout, it gets exception. Because sheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetViews() returns null in that case. How to achieve page layout for existing excel file? I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is strange. Each sheet should have sheet view settings. But you could check whether you get `null` and if then using the appropriate `addNew...` methods. [CTWorksheet.addNewSheetViews](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTWorksheet.java#CTWorksheet.addNewSheetViews%28%29) and [CTSheetViews.addNewSheetView](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTSheetViews.java#CTSheetViews.addNewSheetView%28%29).

Comment: @AxelRichter According to your suggestion now I added `if(sheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetViews() == null){                sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewSheetViews().addNewSheetView();        
}` just before accessing `CTSheetView`. Now, if I save the new excel file by calling `xssfWorkbook.write(outputStream)`, the file is corrupted. Any suggestions?

Comment: As said it is strange that the sheet has not a sheet view. Where is the `Test.xlsx` coming from? Have you unzipped it and looked at `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`? How looks the top part of the `XML` there? Please show it in your question from `<worksheet ...` up to start tag `<sheetData>`.

Comment: @AxelRichter The excel file is coming from SAP Business Intelligence tool, another application. It's original  name is something different. Here is the top part of sheet1.xml: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"><dimension ref="A1:BW758"/><cols><col min="1" max="1" width="22.2383933333333" customWidth="1"/> ...`

Comment: Ah, my friend SAP and its "Office integration". The `CTSheetView` needs an attribute `workbookViewId`. But if it is new added, then it has not a such. So set it using [CTSheetView.setWorkbookViewId](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTSheetView.java#CTSheetView.setWorkbookViewId%28long%29) `view.setView(STSheetViewType.PAGE_LAYOUT); view.setWorkbookViewId((long)0);`. But maybe the `/xl/workbook.xml` also lacks a `<workbookView ... />`. Then this needs also to be set.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter! it works! Now I try to do a few more formatting with the following code, and it breaks the excel file again. `public void customizePrintSetup(boolean landscape){
        XSSFPrintSetup xssfPrintSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup();
        xssfPrintSetup.setLandscape(landscape);
        xssfPrintSetup.setLeftToRight(true);
        xssfPrintSetup.setPaperSize(XSSFPrintSetup.LEGAL_PAPERSIZE);
    }` Can you please help me to fix this one as well? I pass `landscape` to be `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to add the `CTSheetView` if it doesn't exist and also set the `WorkbookViewId`. The modified code is given below:

```
    CTSheetView view;
    if(sheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetViews() == null){
        sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewSheetViews().addNewSheetView();
        view = sheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetViews().getSheetViewArray(0);
        view.setWorkbookViewId((long)0);
    }
    else {
        view = sheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetViews().getSheetViewArray(0);
    }
    view.setView(STSheetViewType.PAGE_LAYOUT);
```

Thanks  Axel Richter for the help.